# REST expected behavior of entity filter within collection

Tags: rest

Could somebody help to find out the expected behavior in filtering data within REST. 
I have an ordinary REST-service with API

- GET /api/articles  <-- extract all articles
- GET /api/articles?category=1  <-- extract all articles belonging the
  particular category

I have doubts regarding the second stuff. What must a request return if user set an invalid category. There're 3 options:

- return all articles
- return an empty collection
- return error

I suppose that it might be up to me, but anyway I wonder whether somebody have implemented this and how he/she resolved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have answered your question yourself, but to provide you an example how this is already implemented (in numerous cases) but just pointing to one such example using JIRA.

You can use JIRA's REST APIs to `GET` the ticket details and which is what I'm showing you here:

[image]

Using `CURL`, I've tried to get the ticket details providing an invalid JIRA ticket id and the above is the response that I received.

It is up to us to decide upon what needs to be the outcome of the REST APIs that we develop, just pointing out one of the scenarios from JIRA REST APIs where they chose to error out (instead of showing no response or etc).

Hope this answers your question well!